# CSS Counter with a Number Padding

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-counter, zero-padding

Is it possible to pad `counter` numbers depending on its value?

```css
div {
  counter-reset: ruler;
}

div > span {
  display: block;
  line-height: 1rem;
}

div > span::before {
  counter-increment: ruler;
  content: counter( ruler ) ' ';
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Hello, World!</span>
  <span>Hello, World!</span>
  <span>Hello, World!</span>
  <span>Hello, World!</span>
  <span>Hello, World!</span>
  <span>Hello, World!</span>
  <span>Hello, World!</span>
  <span>Hello, World!</span>
  <span>Hello, World!</span>
  <span>Hello, World!</span>
  <span>Hello, World!</span>
  <span>Hello, World!</span>
  <span>Hello, World!</span>
</div>
```

Like if there are 42 lines, numbers will be like `09` or  `9`, 420 — `009` or   `9`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS to add leading zero to an ordered list custom counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49910720/css-to-add-leading-zero-to-an-ordered-list-custom-counter)

Comment: Here is a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43014210/6487887 for 3 digits as well. Might help you

Comment: @Sunil that is actually what I wanted! Thank you!

Comment: here is a more generic solution if you don't want the leading zero https://stackoverflow.com/a/58866150/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif wow, this is REALLY helped me — the best solution of all was suggested. I will be using this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use **decimal-leading-zero** inside the counter.

```css
div {
  counter-reset: ruler;
}

div > span {
  display: block;
  line-height: 1rem;
}

div > span::before {
  counter-increment: ruler;
  content: counter( ruler , decimal-leading-zero) ' ';
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Hello, World!</span>
  <span>Hello, World!</span>
  <span>Hello, World!</span>
  <span>Hello, World!</span>
  <span>Hello, World!</span>
  <span>Hello, World!</span>
  <span>Hello, World!</span>
  <span>Hello, World!</span>
  <span>Hello, World!</span>
  <span>Hello, World!</span>
  <span>Hello, World!</span>
  <span>Hello, World!</span>
  <span>Hello, World!</span>
</div>
```

Comment: awesome! didn't know about this. I noticed however that once you get to 100, the numbers before that don't have leading zeros, so the alignment goes off again

Answer (score 0):

Without leading zeroes and aligned right. But since it uses a static width you'd have to adjust that if you expect more than 999 lines.

```js
document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = `<span>Hello, World!</span>`.repeat(150);
```

```css
div {
  counter-reset: ruler;
}

div>span {
  display: block;
  line-height: 1rem;
}

div>span::before {
  counter-increment: ruler;
  content: counter( ruler) '\A0';
  width: 2em;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Hello, World!</span>
  <span>Hello, World!</span>
  <span>Hello, World!</span>
  <span>Hello, World!</span>
  <span>Hello, World!</span>
  <span>Hello, World!</span>
  <span>Hello, World!</span>
  <span>Hello, World!</span>
  <span>Hello, World!</span>
  <span>Hello, World!</span>
  <span>Hello, World!</span>
  <span>Hello, World!</span>
  <span>Hello, World!</span>
</div>
```