# Optimizing a nested list with folding options

Tags: jquery

My question is based on [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75684265/how-can-i-get-margin-exactly-in-the-width-of-imaginary-text-content), but I would like to add a few functions.

The current code looks like that:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ol ol').hide();

  $('li').click(function() {
    $(this).children('ol').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
  cursor: default;
}

ol {
  counter-reset: item;
}

li {
  display: block;
}

li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
  /* content: counters(item, ".", decimal-leading-zero) " "; */
  counter-increment: item;
}

li:has(ol):before {
  float: left;
  /* margin-bottom: 5px; */
}

ol ol {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.active {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ol>
  <li>Coffee
    <ol>
      <li>One</li>
      <li>Two</li>
      <li>Three</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Tea
    <ol>
      <li>One</li>
      <li>Two</li>
      <li>Three</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Cool</li>
</ol>
```

The following is needed:

1. If you click `Coffee` or `Tea`, the the subordinate menu items
   should expand, but with a space from the left starting just below
   the word and not the digit, the way it was solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75684308/12501851).
2. It should only be possible to open one menu item at a time.
3. The menu item clicked last should toggle the `.active` class.
4. If there are more than 9 menu items, all menu items should start
   with a 0 in front of the respective digit so that everything is
   still on the fitting position.

Here is an example how it can look like:

[image]

Does someone know how to do that? I would be very grateful for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would toggle a class and consider all the logic inside the CSS like below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('li').click(function() {
    $('ol.active').removeClass("active");
    $(this).children('ol').addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
  cursor: default;
}

ol {
  counter-reset: item;
}

li {
  display: block;
}

li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
  counter-increment: item;
}
/* add leading 0 if more than 10*/
li:first-child:nth-last-child(n + 10):before,
li:first-child:nth-last-child(n + 10) ~ li:before{
  content: counters(item, ".", decimal-leading-zero) " ";
}

/* select li that has "ol" */
li:has(ol.active):before {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 5px; /* small value */
}

ol ol {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
}
ol ol.active {
  color: green;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ol>
  <li>Coffee
    <ol>
      <li>One</li>
      <li>Two</li>
      <li>Three</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Tea
    <ol>
      <li>One</li>
      <li>Two</li>
      <li>Three</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Cool</li>
</ol>
<hr>
<ol>
  <li>Coffee
    <ol>
      <li>One</li>
      <li>Two</li>
      <li>Three</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Tea
    <ol>
      <li>One</li>
      <li>Two</li>
      <li>Three</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Cool</li>
  <li>Cool</li>
  <li>Cool</li>
  <li>Cool</li>
  <li>Cool</li>
  <li>Cool</li>
  <li>Cool</li>
</ol>
```